# Jmeter failed download library cmdrunner

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I'm trying to install plugin "Selenium/WebDriver support", but got Jmeter failed download library cmdrunner>=2.2 [Error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5kMH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by manually downloading the cmdrunner-2.2.jar file and placing the jar file in my apache-jmeter-4.0\lib directory.

Download link: https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.2/cmdrunner-2.2.jar